# Android SQLite query or insert not working properly

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

First of all I am new to android programming so please go easy of me and thanks in advance. So I have a simple, two activity android blog app. I create blogs in one activity and display them in the other. For the start each blog has the same title and author, but user can insert the content. When I insert content everything seems to be fine. However when I'm loading a blog title displays fine and content stays empty, can anyone help me?

*This is loading code:*

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button loadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
    final TextView titleDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleLoadDisplay);
    final TextView contentDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentLoadDisplay);

    BlogDbHelper dbHelper = new BlogDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    //What I will use after the query
    final String[] projection = {
        BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_TITLE,
        BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT
    };

    if (loadButton != null) {
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = db.query(
                            BlogContract.BlogEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                            projection,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null
                    );

                    res.moveToFirst();
                    if (titleDisplay != null) {
                        titleDisplay.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_TITLE)));
                    }
                    if (contentDisplay != null) {
                        contentDisplay.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT)));
                    }
            }
        });
    }

//        blogList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

*This is uploading code:*

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_blog);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final EditText blogContentInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blogContent);
    String blogContent = null;
    if (blogContentInput != null) {
        blogContent = String.valueOf(blogContentInput.getText());
    }else{
        Log.e("Blog Content","BLog content not instantiated");
    }

    BlogDbHelper dbHelper = new BlogDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (fab != null) {
        final String finalBlogContent = blogContent;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Content", "Blog content " + String.valueOf(blogContentInput.getText()));
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_TITLE, "Practice_02");
                values.put(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_AUTHOR, "MarkoVlaic");
                values.put(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT, String.valueOf(blogContentInput.getText()));
                long newRowId;
                newRowId = db.insertWithOnConflict(BlogContract.BlogEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                blogContentInput.setText("");
                Snackbar.make(view, "You uploaded a blog", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Start by confirming that you have the right `TextView` (use something like `contentDisplay.setText("Test")`, and that the database result is what you'd expect it to be (use something like `Log.d("BLOG CONTENT", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT)))`.

Comment: @BadCash i think it's not the first and second one but it could be third one. Can you explain what you mean in a little bit more detail please?

Comment: @BadCash I tried it, log gives me an empty string

Comment: When you insert a new blog post, do you get the content output in the log? I see that you're using `String.valueOf(blogContentInput.getText())`, but what you really should be doing is using `blogContentInput.getText().toString()`.

Comment: @BadCash Yes I'm logging it out and I get good results. I changed it to blogContentInput.getText().toString() now and it's not working.

Comment: That's very strange, the usual way to get the `String` from a `EditText` is `getText().toString()`... And that's the only part I can see that could be messing up your results. Unless you're displaying the text in the wrong `TextView` or have the `TextView` hidden or something.

Comment: Can you post your XML layout for viewing the posts?

Comment: @BadCash I found a solution, instead of using ´res.moveToFirst()´ I'm using ´res.moveToLast()´. But do you maybe know why ´insertWithOnConflict()´ isnt't working? Thanks for the help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if data is sorted into `database`. Open the `SQLite` `database` and check if `data` exists in the table.

```
// Open the SQLite database file (replace "your_database_name" with the name of your database)
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/your_package_name/databases/your_database_name", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

// Query the database for the data
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + BlogContract.BlogEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);

// Loop over the cursor and print the data
while (res.moveToNext()) {
    String title = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_TITLE));
    String author = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_AUTHOR));
    String content = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT));
    Log.d("Database", "Title: " + title + ", Author: " + author + ", Content: " + content);
}

// Close the cursor and database
res.close();
db.close();
```

---

You have to properly init the `contentDisplay TextView` in your code. It may be `null` causing the `setText()` to fail.

```
final TextView contentDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentLoadDisplay);

if (contentDisplay != null) {
    contentDisplay.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT)));
} else {
    Log.e("Content Display", "Content display not instantiated");
}
```

---

Instead of `res.moveToFirst()` use a loop to iterate the rows and retrieve `data`.

```
while (res.moveToNext()) {
    String title = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_TITLE));
    String content = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(BlogContract.BlogEntry.BLOG_CONTENT));
    // Do something with title and content
}
```

---

Other potential issue can be how you retrieve the blog content in your uploading code. Change `String.valueOf(blogContentInput.getText())` with `blogContentInput.getText().toString()`

```
String blogContent = blogContentInput.getText().toString();
```

---

Check that the `layout` file of `MainActivity` has `TextView` with the correct IDs, and it has to be properly inflated in the method.

```
// Inflate the layout and find the TextViews
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView titleDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleLoadDisplay);
TextView contentDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentLoadDisplay);
```